# Controlling rate of endothermic reaction

Tags: reaction-mechanism, thermodynamics, kinetics, reaction-control

In an experiment, I have two endothermic reactions taking place simultaneously:

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{A + B &-> C + D}\tag{1}\\
\ce{E + G &-> Z + F}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

$\ce{C}$ and $\ce{Z}$ also take place in a reaction to form the final product of the process $\ce{J}$. In my experiment, I have to use a single heating source, and cannot change the concentration of the chemicals in $\ce{A + B}$ and $\ce{E + G}$ such that the production of $\ce{J}$ is as fast as possible. How can I find the optimum temperature for this reaction, and will it be useful?

It is my theory that

$$\frac{\text{rate}_1 + \text{rate}_2}{2}$$

can be found when both reactions take place in water heated by a single source, and the activation energies are known. However, there is a need for another factor other than concentration and heat which needs to ensure that the products $\ce{C}$ and $\ce{Z}$ are produced at such rates (independently and at different rates) which will ensure an efficient process.

Comment: Usually endothermic reactions don't produce one product out of two reactants. Here you seem to have two such endothermic reaction simultaneously. It is hard to believe. And why is it a zero order reaction ? Please be more explicit !

Comment: Do you know quantitatively the kinetics of the reactions involved, and the heats of the reactions?!